# CKEditor image upload - getting the upload file

Tags: file, post, upload, ckeditor

I was working on a very simple and fast image uploader for CKEditor. It works all like a charm, the only problem now is the actual upload. I thought it would all be easy, but now I am stuck.

I have the CK file-field and figured I could just run an ajax request to my php uploading script, the problem is now: how do i get the file data to upload it. The Ajax does not have the post values, so I am lost.

Please lead me into the right direction.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i now used an iFrame with the form in it. Using uplodify in the iframe it put the path to the file in a hidden input which I can extract from the frame and use as the src form my image in CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Ajax to post the form, your file upload function should be able to get the values from the form as usual.

For example, see this article: http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-ajax-upload-example

Comment: Well, the thing is, that I use the CKEditor button to post the form, so it would need to work with their dialog scheme.